# Conditional Probability Question relating to two dice.

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm taking a beginner Statistics class, and I'm stumped by a conditional probability example. Here is the question:

Roll two dice. If one die is a 6, what is the probability that the total of the dice is 10?

P(A) = Rolled a 6

P(B) = Total is 10

P(B|A) = ???

.............................................................................

Intuitive answer: If one die is a 6, the only way they add up to 10 is if the other die is 4. There is a 1/6 chance of rolling a 4. Therefore: P(B|A) = 1/6

.............................................................................

Formulaic answer:

$P(B|A) = P(B \cap A)/P(A)$

$P(B \cap A) = 2/36$ (out of 36 combinations of dice, there are only 2 that have a 6 and add up to 10: 6 and 4 or 4 and 6).

$P(A) = 11/36$

$P(B|A) = P(B \cap A)/P(A) = (2/36)/(11/36) = 2/11$

.............................................................................

The intuitive answer (1/6) and the formulaic answer (2/11) are very close, but not the same. Can you help me understand why?

We haven't yet gotten to Baye's Theorem. Maybe Bayes helps explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one die is a 6, the only way they add up to 10 is if the other die is 4.

You don't know which die is the six and there is a chance that they both are.   It is this common outcome that is throwing off your intuition, since it means there are *not* six **equally probable** results for the "other die".

There are eleven equally probable ways two die can roll such that "at least one is a '6'" and two of these outcomes have the other dice a '4'.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I inferred "the first die is a 6" when that wasn't implied by the question. I see how that could very slightly affect the odds.